# Azure API Authentication and MSGraph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking into a Node.JS API that has authentication through Azure AD, which all seems to be working ok, when i pass access token generated by logging into the web app, it authenticates and returns data.

However i now need the API to access MSGraph to retrieve Profile Photo etc.  Ho do i pass authentication to MSGraph, i believe the accesstoken is different isnt it because they are different scopes.  So how do i generate a new accesstoken for MSGrpah after i have logged into my app.

API endpoint just queries a db of users returning a JSON response, but i want to append the users profile image in base64Image to the response.

How do i do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

[image]

**Sample:**

```
POST /oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id=2846f71b-a7a4-4987-bab3-760035b2f389
&client_secret=BYyVnAt56JpLwUcyo47XODd
&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIyODQ2ZjcxYi1hN2E0LTQ5ODctYmFiMy03NjAwMzViMmYzODkiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vNzJmOTg4YmYtODZmMS00MWFmLTkxYWItMmQ3Y2QwMTFkYjQ3L3YyLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTM5MjA5MTYsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MzkyMDkxNiwiZXhwIjoxNDkzOTI0ODE2LCJhaW8iOiJBU1FBMi84REFBQUFnZm8vNk9CR0NaaFV2NjJ6MFFYSEZKR0VVYUIwRUlIV3NhcGducndMMnVrPSIsIm5hbWUiOiJOYXZ5YSBDYW51bWFsbGEiLCJvaWQiOiJkNWU5NzljNy0zZDJkLTQyYWYtOGYzMC03MjdkZDRjMmQzODMiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJuYWNhbnVtYUBtaWNyb3NvZnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZ1Q5a1FMN2hXRUpUUGg1OWJlX1l5dVZNRDFOTEdiREJFWFRhbEQzU3FZYyIsInRpZCI6IjcyZjk4OGJmLTg2ZjEtNDFhZi05MWFiLTJkN2NkMDExZGI0NyIsInV0aSI6IjN5U3F4UHJweUVPd0ZsTWFFMU1PQUEiLCJ2ZXIiOiIyLjAifQ.TPPJSvpNCSCyUeIiKQoLMixN1-M-Y5U0QxtxVkpepjyoWNG0i49YFAJC6ADdCs5nJXr6f-ozIRuaiPzy29yRUOdSz_8KqG42luCyC1c951HyeDgqUJSz91Ku150D9kP5B9-2R-jgCerD_VVuxXUdkuPFEl3VEADC_1qkGBiIg0AyLLbz7DTMp5DvmbC09DhrQQiouHQGFSk2TPmksqHm3-b3RgeNM1rJmpLThis2ZWBEIPx662pjxL6NJDmV08cPVIcGX4KkFo54Z3rfwiYg4YssiUc4w-w3NJUBQhnzfTl4_Mtq2d7cVlul9uDzras091vFy32tWkrpa970UvdVfQ
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

Comment: If i had my API that gets passed a Bearer token from the front end(from Azure AD) andone of the end points needs to call MGraph, would the best way to just have a function that creates the new token calls the MSgraph endpoint and return required data. OR create new endpoints on my API that are authenticated using new token (if this is possibile)

Comment: @AndyCollins The access_token is time-limited, and you need to use the refresh_token to update it. So I think it is a better way to have a function.